# 3D object rendering in openCV using metaio in Android

Tags: android, opencv, 3d, augmented-reality, metaio

I am developing an appication, wher I'm using opencv to detect shapes in a camera image and want to display 3D objects rendered by metaio on those shapes. How can this be achieved? I have tried custom rendering, but 'onNewCameraFrame' method is not being called.

I have to convert each camera frame that we get in 'onNewCameraFrame()' method to Mat object for shape detection logic. But it's not being called. I have even added call to 'requestCameraImage()' method of metaio sdk.

Comment: Have you tried running the opencv examples in order to check if these work?
If you're using the native grabber; that could also be the problem as it doesn't work on all phones.

Comment: I have used openCV examples, but what I want is metaio camera view and not openCV.

Comment: @Shweta24. Were you able to find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @VizZy : nope. I was not able to get any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the Hello world example by metaio: http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tutorials/hello-world/ There you can see the example code how to e.g. render a figure on a marker

But metaio and OpenVC are not for the rendering part, well metaio a little bit more then OpenCV but they do the computer vision part of your application. To render something you have to write OpenGL code yourself, or you conect the tracking of metaio to some more complex rendering engine like jMonkey, libGDX etc.

Comment: I have gone through basic tutorials of metaio. Metaio free version does not support edge detection, which can be done by openCV. So, I was wondering, how both(OpenCV and Metaio) can be combined => like what I did was detected basic shapes using edge detection in openCV. And now I want to add 3d object on detected shape using metaio. How can this be done.

Comment: I think you can't do it, read the terms of use, I think you are not allowed to use both OpenCV and metaio computer vision methods at the same time

Comment: What you can do is use something like the droidar marker tracker: https://code.google.com/p/droidar/wiki/Markerdetection and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5BrHLnG4no , but this would mean that you need to write some tracking logic with opencv yourself